# Read/write files in shared drive from web application hosted on iis

Tags: c#, iis

We have two server in same domain. On one server (SERVER1) we have folder "C:\AppFiles\Production\Inbound" and shared AppFiles folder as a drive (AppFiles (O:)) to another server (SERVER2) and we are manually able to place files in shared drive (O:\Production\Inbound) on SERVER2. But we want to read/write files in shared drive (O:\Production\Inbound) from our mvc web application hosted on SERVER2.

We are getting below error in provided code when try to read/write in shared drive (O:\Production\

```
 public void Writefile()
 {
  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(@"O:\Production\Inbound", "testlog.txt"), "test test, text");
 }
```

**error:**

> Could not find a part of the path 'O:\Production\Inbound\testlog.txt'.

Please suggest how i can read/write files in shared drive from application hosted on iis.

Comment: Network drives are per Windows user. A network drive may be setup for the user you are logged in with but your IIS Application pool might be running under a different username.

Comment: My application pool is running on default identity and identity set as "ApplicationPoolIdentity". Is it possible to share the drive for iis default user.

Comment: Please read this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Comment: Mapped drives are not supported by IIS at all. Use UNC paths.

Answer (score 0):

Mapped drives are not supported on IIS, rather you can use UNC paths. Try changing the path to the following:

```
\\SERVER1\C$\AppFiles\Production\Inbound
```

If both the servers are on the same network and you can access the above link from server 2, the it should work.